# Different way of specifying a view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am just looking at a code sample and I notice something I have not seen before:

```
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MenuRatingModel();
        List entries = new List();
        model.ListEntries = new []
                                {
                                    new MenuRatingListEntryModel(),
                                    new MenuRatingListEntryModel(),
                                    new MenuRatingListEntryModel(),
                                    new MenuRatingListEntryModel()
                                };
        return View(Views.Index, model);
    }
```

Here the developer specifies "Views.Index" in the return. Can someone explain why this is. Would it not be easier just to omit that?

Answer (score 3):

I think the developer created some kind of Enum/Const class, where all the names of all the views are stored. The View-method accepts a string for the name of the view you would like to render. A problem with providing a string, is that it is more difficult to refactor and it is more error-prown (i.e. typos). If you may decide to rename a view, you will have to change the name everywhere you use the name of the view.

By creating a static class, you can store all names of the Views in one place. In the case one of the names of a view changes, you will only have to change this in one place.

e.g.

```
public static class Views
{
    public const string Index = "Index";
    public const string SomeOtherView = "SomeOtherView";
}
```

Comment: But isn't it just cleaner to not even put that there? Seems like additional work for no gain.

Comment: I believe they are using `T4MVC` which auto generates the static class when you build.

Comment: Like I said, it can prevent making typo's and refactoring can be easier. But when using a tool like Resharper, I agree this can seem like extra work.

Answer (score 1):

They could omit that. It looks as they are doing that as a standard wherever so there are no 'magic strings' that could be misspelled. Also you can right click a view and easily find out ALL locations it is referenced which is probably a major reason they did this.